# Есть ли способ закрыть блок при клике на его after?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Давно мучает этот вопрос меня , реализовал для примера вот такую конструкцию :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box1:after").click(function(){
        $(".box1").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:1;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
section{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position:relative;
}
.box1{
  width:50%;
  min-height:200px;
  max-height:450px;
  padding:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  bottom:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  background:#fff;
}
.box1 p{
  font:800 20px Georgia;
  color:#909090;
  line-height:1.7;
}
.box1:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:#909090;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin:3px;
  transition:all .1s;
}
.box1:hover:after{
  content:"close";
  width:60px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<section> 
 <div class="box1"> 
   <p>People tend to read writing. Default text is for web developers and designers that need default text quickly. If it is not real text, they will focus on the design. Default text is for web developers and designers that need default text quickly. I hope you enjoyed the fake text. A designer can use default text to simulate what text would look like. Using default text is a simple way to create the appearance of content without having to create it. Thank you for using this application. This text will not appear in a consistent order. This string is randomly  generated.</p>
</div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></scrip
```

**существует ли способ , без дополнительной резметки (html) закрыть родителя box1 при клике на его after ? имеется ввиду close , в сниппете видно кнопка повляется при `hover`**

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/BzYjNX  это пример в песочнице

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть следующее решение проблемы. Убираем эвенты у `.box1` `pointer-events: none;`, ставим на псевдоэлемент `.box1:after` `pointer-events: all;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.box1").click(function() {
      $('.box1').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:1;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
section{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position:relative;
}
.box1{
  width:50%;
  min-height:200px;
  max-height:450px;
  padding:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  bottom:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  background:#fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.box1 p{
  font:800 20px Georgia;
  color:#909090;
  line-height:1.7;
}
.box1:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:#909090;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin:3px;
  transition:all .1s;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.box1:hover:after{
  content:"close";
  width:60px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<section> 
 <div class="box1"> 
   <p>People tend to read writing. Default text is for web developers and designers that need default text quickly. If it is not real text, they will focus on the design. Default text is for web developers and designers that need default text quickly. I hope you enjoyed the fake text. A designer can use default text to simulate what text would look like. Using default text is a simple way to create the appearance of content without having to create it. Thank you for using this application. This text will not appear in a consistent order. This string is randomly  generated.</p>
</div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doofy почему в моём случае  не работает ?

Comment: Не понимаю, как это работает. Shadow dom же, как в jQuery его захакали? Поделитесь ссылкой на объяснение?

Comment: @Geyan, так, только что проверял работало. Щя проверю ещё раз

Comment: @Doofy только не по самому box закрыть а именно по after

Comment: @Geyan, там `</script>` не закрыт. В коде вопроса `"></scrip`

Comment: закрыл но блок так же закрывается и по клику на нём самом , а надо только по клику на after т.е  на close и больше ни где , 2 года я с этим борюсь

Comment: Нет, вы не правы. Метод .after() используется для вставки контента после элемента и возвращает оригинальную выборку, на которой его вызвали. Таким образом, вы просто обрабатываете клик по .box, псевдоэлементы в этом никак не участвуют.

Comment: @АлексейУколов, да, не проверил

Comment: @Алексей всё таки ваш ответ лучший

Comment: @Doofy, добавьте пояснение в текст вопроса, пожалуйста, а то важные комментарии скрыты и люди могут посчитать, что код рабочий.

Comment: @Geyan, обновил, прадва текст уже не выделить и не скопировать

Comment: Doofy 100% решение - как мне тебе баллы отдать ?

Answer (score 3):

Псевдоэлементы before и after (и все остальные псевдоэлементы) - это shadow dom, они скрыты браузером от манипуляции через javascript. Поэтому, на них невозможно повесить обработчики событий, невозможно получить и изменить их стили и т.п.

Исходя из этого, вашу задачу решить средствами js невозможно.

Такую задачу можно попробовать решить на чистом css при помощи чекбоксов или псевдокласса target (это обычные средства для реализации табов, всплывающих окон и т.п. на css), но я сходу не соображу, насколько эта техника совместима с псевдоэлементами.

Comment: я два года пробую решить это , борюсь и с выходом новой версии jquery пробую и не фига не получается , но что ж поделать - раз так то Галочка ваша но другой специалист мне помог и вроде работает - смотрите : http://codepen.io/Letsrock/pen/KrQVNg

Comment: Так ведь в примере по ссылке без псевдоэлементов сделано, в этом-то ничего сложного.

Comment: Сразу не заметил